# How to style this label so it's not spilling out of the chart?

Tags: apexcharts, ng-apexcharts

I have a horizontal bar chart which I added an offsetX to put the labels to the right. Consequently, some labels are spilling out of the graph's bounds:

[image: label spilling out of the grid on the right]

I think increasing the width or decreasing the font size would help, but I don't have control over that unfortunately.

I also noticed the spacing between the labels and the bars isn't consistent even though offsetX is a fixed number, so any ideas on fixing that would be appreciated too.